# Specifying the android SDK Build Tools version in build.grandle does not remove warning in React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this warning when I perform npx react-native run-android

```
WARNING:: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (29.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (30.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 4.2.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 30.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
```

Although I already modified this parameter in my build.grandle file as you can see here:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = '30.0.2'
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
        kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1')
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Also, I already clean my project and re-build it in android studio but still get the same warning when I perform npx react-native run-android

I am missing something?

Comment: On a related note - jcenter sunsetting: https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/